# request number of lines that have same cell, too

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I want to display not only all cells of a table but also want to display on each line how many cells shares the `c3`-column's content.

e.g.

```
c1   c2   c3   count(c3)
1    2    3    1
2    3    1    2
3    2    1    2
```

I tried using a inner select request, but I'm a bit rusty and probably made a mistake using it:

```
select u.c1,u.c2,u.c3,s.c from mytable u, (select count(s.c3) as c from mytable s group by s.c3) where s.c3==u.c3
```

Do you know the correct request for a table output like this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's my lack of consistency^^ Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join the original query with an aggregate query:

```
SELECT u.c1, u.c2, u.c3, v.cnt
FROM   my_table u
JOIN   (SELECT   c3, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM     my_table
        GROUP BY c3) v ON u.c3 = v.c3
```